# Ubuntu 16.04 with Linux 4.4.0-83, is it outdated?

Tags: 16.04, wireless, broadcom, lts

I am a new to Ubuntu with 1 month of experience and I really like it. I am a web developer with Windows environment background. Since my new employer using Linux as their servers (Redhats and Ubuntu), so I take initiative to experience myself with Linux environment and thinking to fully switch from windows environment to Linux environment via Ubuntu. Even my manager using Linux but not sure which distro he is using.

My question is, my laptop (Acer Aspire E15) currently set to dual boots with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 with Linux 4.4.0-83. Is it outdated and I need to update to newest version or still relevant just continue to use it?

Below is my result when query : uname -mrs

> Linux 4.4.0-83-generic x86_64

--The story how I get to this version--

My 1st set up was Ubuntu with Linux with Linux 4.8.0-58-generic. I found out that this version couldn't let my laptop connect to the wifi. I already forget what I do because there were a lot of try with several method and solution but it is seems to no avail. Until one day I discovered Ubuntu with advance boot. I try the lowest version which is Ubuntu with Linux 4.4.0-83. Thank god that this version can connect to Wifi.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest kernel version for Ubuntu 16.04 is currently 4.4.0-89-generic. You can update the kernel to the latest version using the Software Updater. Ubuntu 16.04 is a long term support release which is supported by updates until April, 2021. Ubuntu is designed to be a secure operating system which is updated regularly. If you continue to update your operating system regularly using the Software Updater, your OS will be fine until April, 2021.

Comment: Hi Karel, thanks for your reply and explanation. Much Appreciated!

Basically, I am in the right version for Ubuntu 16.04 version right? Just need to update my Kernel to the 4.4.0-89-generic correct?

May I know Ubuntu with Linux with Linux 4.8.0-58-generic is for what version? Is it a latest unstable version or else? I thought I download the correct Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  version last time.

Comment: The Linux kernels in Ubuntu are updated regularly to fix bugs and security vulnerabilities and also to add more devices to the list of supported hardware. The latest kernel version offered by the Software Updater application is supposed to be the correct one in all Ubuntu releases including Ubuntu 16.04, however occasionally due to a bug in a kernel update it is necessary to select an earlier kernel version in the GRUB boot menu until the kernel bug is fixed. In all the time I have used Ubuntu the latest kernel update has failed me only once and this bug was fixed three updates later.

Comment: The default kernel version series in Ubuntu 16.04 is the 4.4 series of which 4.4.0-89-generic is the latest version. The Linux 4.8.0-58-generic  kernel you are referring to is named *linux-signed-image-4.8.0-58-generic* iinm. For further information about signed Linux kernel images see this question: [What does a signed Linux kernel image get me?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/89291/what-does-a-signed-linux-kernel-image-get-me).

Comment: I see, what I understand is that when a new version come out, previous bugs and security issues should be fixed. But, there is a chance a new bug emerge from the new updated kernel. As long I update my Ubuntu with Software Updater should be fine. Currently I have some errors when updating my Ubuntu, but I guess I will open another question if I really into it. Other things are working in awesome condition. Is there any tips you like to add for me as newbie?

Comment: As for the explanation of default version series  in Ubuntu 16.04, I taken note on that. Thank you very much. Other things I will further study for it.

Comment: I'm a programmer and I need to install tons of crap software on my computer, but I never install crap software in my root filesystem. I install it in my home directory, in a Python virtual environment or in a virtual machine, but never in my root filesystem. I almost always install software only from the Ubuntu Software application. In a VM I frequently restore back to an earlier snapshot when I am finished using a dodgy software or delete the old VM entirely and install a new one. It's the same as the advice frequently given to Windows users - don't download crap and don't install crap.

Comment: Awesome Karel, I will look into it as for what you suggest. Btw, I am PHP programmer more on web development. Sometimes doing front end which amend the layout, functionalities and content of web pages request by users. Hopefully it will assist me to be more productive compared on Windows environment. Thank you again Karel, have a nice day ahead!